# Inheritence in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
class person {
    private: char name[50];
             int age;
    public: void get_name() {
                cout<<"Enter name"<<endl;
                gets(name);
            }
            void put_name() {
                cout<<"Name : ";
                puts(name);
                cout<<endl;
            }
            void get_age() {
                cout<<"Enter age"<<endl;
                cin>>age;
            }
            void put_age() {
                cout<<"Age : "<<age<<endl;
            }
};
class student : public person {
    private : int roll;
    public : void get_roll() {
                cout<<"Enter roll"<<endl;
                cin>>roll;
             }
             void put_roll() {
                cout<<"Roll : "<<roll<<endl;
             }
};
int main() {
    student A;
    A.get_name();
    A.get_roll();
    A.get_age();
    A.put_name();
    A.put_age();
    A.put_roll();
    getch();
    clrscr();
    return 0;
}
```

There are following queries:

- If private members of class `person` are not inherited in class `student` then how can an instance of class `student` store values in them?
- Shouldn't the variables just not exist in the class `student`?

**Note:** I am using old compiler for a college project.

Comment: None of the class `student` methods access `person` class private members. Doing so would result in compilation error. Both `age` and `name` exist in class `student` instances, however you never access them directly, only through public get / put methods.

Comment: Remember that inheritance is an "is a" relationship. The class `student` *is a* `person`. Therefore when you call member functions defined in the `person` class it can access the private members of its own class (since the object *is a* `person` as well as a `student`).

Comment: Why do you think private members are not inherited? There's a difference between things you can't reach and things that don't exist.

Comment: Your use of `iostream.h` strongly indicates to me that you are using Turbo-C++. You should know that compiler is more than old, it's ancient, and it won't teach you anything about C++ as it is used today.

Comment: TBH these particular bits (access levels for straightforward inheritance) haven't changed in the last two decades - they're pretty fundamental. Roughly speaking, the problems of teaching Turbo-C++ can be divided in 10% wrong, 30% still legal today but bad practice, and 60% missing modern functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a Student wants to access the Person fields, the simplest way is make them **protected**, so they can be accessed by all derived class of Person.
Another way is use **public getter/setter methods** (you can even set them protected, but at this point is better use protected fields), in this way all classes can see and set the fields of Person.
Indeed, even if a variable is declared **private** in the base class, it exist in the derived class ( a Student is in any case a Person, so the field in Person must be initialized) but it can't be reached by her.

Answer (score 0):

`A` is an object of type `Student` and it can access `protected` or `public` member function and data member of class `Person`. Now answer to your query, you are trying to use the function of class `Person` using object of class `Student` which is possible (as inherited publicly) and since the function and those private data member are part of same class (`Person`), so those function can use the variable.

Note : `private`, `public` and `protected` member have no effect within same class.

Comment: Actually, the access specifiers _do_ have a function within a class, but that is rather specialized knowledge. A beginner can ignore that.